The reduction of the dimensionality of a system of PDE's.
To transform an $ n $th-order linear ordinary differential equation (ODE) into a system of $ n $ first-order ODEs, you use a change of variables by introducing new variables to represent the higher-order derivatives. Here’s how you do it:
Given an $ n$th-order ODE:
$$ y^{(n)} + a_{n-1}(t)y^{(n-1)} + \cdots + a_1(t)y' + a_0(t)y = g(t) $$
Introduce the new variables:
$$ y_1 = y, \quad y_2 = y', \quad y_3 = y'', \quad \ldots, \quad y_n = y^{(n-1)} $$
Then the system of first-order ODEs becomes:
\begin{cases}
\frac{dy_1}{dt} = y_2 \\
\frac{dy_2}{dt} = y_3 \\
\vdots \\
\frac{dy_{n-1}}{dt} = y_n \\
\frac{dy_n}{dt} = -a_{n-1}(t)y_n - a_{n-2}(t)y_{n-1} - \cdots - a_1(t)y_2 - a_0(t)y_1 + g(t)
\end{cases}
This system represents the original $ n $th-order ODE as a set of $n $ first-order ODEs.
An $ n $th-order linear partial differential equation (PDE) in $ m $ spatial dimensions can be written in the general form:
$$
\sum_{|\alpha| \leq n} a_{\alpha}(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m, t) \frac{\partial^{|\alpha|} u}{\partial x_1^{\alpha_1} \partial x_2^{\alpha_2} \cdots \partial x_m^{\alpha_m}} = f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m, t)$$
where:

$( x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m )$ are the spatial variables.
$ t$ is the time variable.
$ u = u(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m, t) $ is the unknown function.
$ \alpha = (\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_m) $ is a multi-index with $|\alpha| = \alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \cdots + \alpha_m $.
$ a_{\alpha}(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m, t) $ are the coefficient functions.
$ \frac{\partial^{|\alpha|} u}{\partial x_1^{\alpha_1} \partial x_2^{\alpha_2} \cdots \partial x_m^{\alpha_m}} $ denotes the partial derivatives of $ u $ of order $ |\alpha| $.
$f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m, t) $ is a given function.

Is there is a way to change a higher order linear PDE into a multidimensional system of one order PDEs the same way we can do with  scalar linear ODEs?

Do you find an obstruction doing the "obvious" thing?  $u_1 = \partial u/\partial x_1$, $u_2 = \partial u/\partial x_2$, ..., $u_{1,1} = \partial u_1/\partial x_1$, $u_{1,2} = \partial u_1/\partial x_2$, ...
